# Dropdown issues in WPF Webbrowser control when viewing IE11 compatible website

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF application, in which we are using webbrowser control to view asp.net website which is created according to latest IE-11Edge Mode.

In this website we have multiple dropdown controls. when we click on the dropdown in webbrowser control, its popup container width is less than dropdown width. Even if, we press the [esc] key to close the popup container of dropdown, it is also not working.

Approaches I have tried to resolved this issue;

1. I have added meta tag in asp.net page
2. I have register my WPF application .exe file name in registery on [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION] path with value 11001.

But unfortunately none of them are working.

Please suggest any solution in this case.

Thanks & Regards,

Ajay Singh

Comment: if you are using visiual studio, then you need to enable Emulation for application.vshost.exe also

Comment: If you are using a 32bit app you need to put the registry key in the Wow6432Node

Comment: I tried both of the solutions but none of them are working.

Comment: Have you tried with 11000 instead of 11001?

Comment: And try to add a doctype https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks all of you for responding. I have tried with 11000 and doctype approach but still issue is persist.

Comment: I have added issue with sample code and screenshot on following link : [Please check the link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a68fe22-e138-43cf-ac46-1778b690c654/dropdown-issues-in-wpf-webbrowser-control-when-viewing-ie11-compatible-website?forum=wpf)